# extended REs in Emacs lgrep?

Tags: emacs

The defaults for M-x lgrep is to use -e for the pattern.  I'd like to use -E, but it looks like -e is hard-coded into grep.el.  Tell me I'm wrong!  Any hints?  (I'm using version 22.1 - is the grass any greener in 23?)

Answer (score 3):

If you use a `C-u` prefix to `M-x lgrep`, you can edit the resulting command line before it's executed. `grep-command` is the default command string used by Emacs' various grep functions, and you can do `M-x customize-variable RET grep-command` to change it.

Answer (score 0):

If understand your problem, the solution may be changing the **grep-command** variable.

This variable has default value set to: "grep -nH -e " and you probably want to change "-e" to "-E"